# Draw over camera using JAVA ME

Tags: java-me, camera, lwuit

I'm wondering if there is anyway for drawing somethin over the videoControl.
I tried using LWUIT but I can't achieve any result, have anybody done somethin similar? Any help will be appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Nope very few devices will support this.  JSR135 camera viewfinder images seem to get drawn by the hardware external to Java, and it gets drawn over whatever you already have on the screen.  Nothing you can do about it :(

Comment: Even if some few devices support it, could you post any example code?

Comment: Maybe should clarify, in my fairly extensive JSR135 experience, I have never seen ANY devices which support this (hence the line "Drawing any graphics or rendering other video at the same region on the canvas may not be supported." in the Javadoc for VideoControl.USE_GUI_PRIMITIVE).  If it were to be supported I guess it would just be to use regular Graphics methods on the paint() method of your canvas.

Comment: So, the only options is to move to an specific development environment like Symbian or Android?.
Does LWUIT help in anything?

Answer (score 0):

If you're application user don't argue slow refresh rate I think you can use snapshot feature of VideoControl.

- Do not show preview of VideoControl (Hide, Make it's size as zero ...)
- Take snapshot from VideoControl
- Draw captured image on Canvas
- Draw something on it
- Do it repeatedly

LWUIT do not help for this issue. It's just graphical widget library on the MIDP Canvas.